# Optimizing XML In TSQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery, sql-server-2012

I have recently started working with XML in table columns using TSQL, and found that it is horrendously slower than your average everyday `3rd-Normal-Form-associative-tables-Query-joining`, from my tests conducted with 1.5 million rows, I mean it is 8 times slower than `3rd-Normal-Form-associative-tables-Query-joining`. The upside is that with XML, if set up in an specific way, it prevents you from setting up extra associative tables (in my tests, my associative tables (join tables for many=many relationships got to 7.5 million rows in size, in comparison to my table with the XML which was 1.5 million rows in size storing the same information). Don't mind my ranting though, this was only tests on 2 sets of tables which I have performed.

**Question**

Its kind of hard to explain for me, as I am just a beginner-intermediate with SQL Server. What is the best practices for using Untyped XML in your columns, and how can you optimize the tables containing this XML to perform at optimal speeds, seeing as I must now deal with XPath and XQuery withing SQL Scripts now (which seems to be the cause of the severe speed slowdown according to execution plans)?

Comment: I don't think you can directly compare XML documents stored in one column with normalized data stored in multiple columns (or tables): they're different approaches to storing the same data, and which one is better depends on how you work with the database. If performance is your main concern, you may be better off using the normalized table approach, even if it takes more development time to implement. And looking at table rowcount is not very useful in this context: 7.5m rows isn't much if the table is properly designed and indexed.

Comment: You see, the normalized approach is hands-down faster than XML, but because of a slight oversight from my co-workers, they have planned to store data as comma seperated values in the columns, requiring client side splitting to use this information.  We concluded that the development time is becoming critical for this operation since this table had been redesigned a whopping 14 times now. Speed is not a super critical issue here (our servers are omnipotent in strength), but every little performance we can squeeze out of this query will deliver a better client-side experience to the user. Thanks

Comment: is there a speed difference storing the data as xml-value or xml-attribute ?
  <part prop42="110V - 220V" />    or

  <part>
     <prop42>"110V - 220V"</prop42> 
  </part>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you can do to improve the performance of xml fields

- Add a primary XML index
- Add Secondary index
- Use an XML Schema
- Create a calculated field that extracts out data from the XML

XML fields tend to be slightly less IO intensive but much more CPU intensive. Check if that is an issue

Comment: I have checked out some of your approaches today and also found things like declaring a single root node (telling TSQL that the root node is a singleton) and I only saw small changes (like 0.8 second speedups from queries on AVERAGE) by implementing some of your plans. In the end, it doesn't really matter too much. the expected size of this table will anyway be just 200000 rows and not 1.5 million, so its no live-or-die issue. Thanks again.